How do you embed one object into another object yet stay visible?
I have flat 2D eyes that I want to slightly embed into my rounded 3D character without sculpting into the character. I’m trying to stop the gap between the eyes and character. Visibility priority (?)  but only from certain angles. The head bends forward a bit and when the eyes are close to the head parts of the eyes disappear.  I want the eyes to always be visible but not when the character’s turned around. How you’d normally see eyes when a head rotates. I don’t know the proper terms. If you can help please explain in very simple terms. Go to this page, press this, disable that etc. Thanks if you can help.

Try to add a shrinkwrap with a little offset

"How you’d normally see eyes when a head rotates." Well, normally eyes are not totally flat, that's why you call them eyeballs. Your eyes are flat, so even if you get them closer to the head with e.g. a Shrinkwrap modifier like @DanielMöller suggests, they would still be quite flat (compared to the head's surface), even though they would follow the curve of the head - provided that your eyes have enough geometry to get bent, but you do not show any mesh information in your question.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/51973/19307

In movies i worked on, when there was a need to fake 2d in 3d, or even simply to make an appealing 2d shape from 3d (which is always what you do in fine with 3d rendered as a flat image), a common solution is to bend the 3d model to "look right in the camera". Here it's not just a matter of making your eyes show up on top of the mesh, they meed to be oriented in a certain way toward the camera. The head mesh needs yo adapt accordingly. Perhaps there aere ways to sort of get there with automated ways, but in terms of means, a simple deformation rig with bones would do the job too.
