# Why edges of my design suddenly overlapping other objects in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, edges

While everything was going good with my design I started noticing some edges started showing up on other object. I am not sure if I messed up a setting or checked some checkbox, has anyone stumbled upon this, or knows what is wrong [image]

the cylinders face looks like it is inside the edges

[image]

but it is actually in correct place

[image]

Comment: Ah yes, very common.  [This answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1387/2217) explains it fully. In short, just lower the Max clipping distance.

Comment: Yeap! I just found out. I set it to 10m and that was the only setting I could remember changing. setting 1m back fixed it. But thank you.