# Wireframe become x-ray alike in edit mode

Tags: modeling, wireframe

[image: The xray ed wireframe]

I don't know what i've clickin, but somehow this happening. when i enter edit mode, the wireframe in the backside keeps showing on, and i can't choose the proper faces which i want, pls help me :D

Comment: This is most likely related to [clipping problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/shadows-along-edges-of-mesh-in-3d-view). Also the mesh might behave more as expected if you turn off Subsurf in Edit mode.

Comment: There are three selection options in Edit Mode -  Vertex/Edge/Face. You currently have selected Vertex Select. You may want to choose Face Select instead. The icon is a cube with an orange face (it's the button to the left of the one in the image Nils Eisen posted in his answer).

Answer (score 1):

Deselect this icon in the bottom:

[image]

Comment: This will essentially do the opposite; [Limit Selection to Visible](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/introduction.html#limit-selection-to-visible) prevents the backside geometry to be visible/selectable if it's *enabled*. In the OP's case it seems to be the clipping problem.