# Visual artifacts when seeing an object form afar in Edit Mode

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, camera, artifacts

I'm trying to model a double sided cabinet using metric units (if thats helpful) and I'm seeing both inside and outside faces without enabling wireframe mode or something like this. Does anyone know how I can avoid those artifacts? The problem appears only when I am relatively far from the object(but not so far) and only in edit mode and while using orthographic view.

[image: Im having those double faces as shown here]

Comment: Those generally aren't related to metric or whatever unit system, it's known as z-fighting because of too big difference in the  clipping values. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/shadows-along-edges-of-mesh-in-3d-view

Comment: Did you check clipping? https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1385/26720

Comment: Thanks that was it. I had something like 10cm lowest and 100m highest as my clipping values