# Model great, but mesh is very weird!

Tags: modeling, mesh

I do not know how to explain what is happening, I imported a model that I had saved some time ago. But it is with the mesh in a very strange way.

I already checked play for a new project, normals, remove doubles, decimate, merge vertex loose, but nothing solves!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try to Remove Doubles in Edit Mode. Select All > W > Remove Doubles.

Comment: Check the clipping values for the viewport. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/shadows-along-edges-of-mesh-in-3d-view

Answer (score 1):

Changing Clip value solved my problem!

The models were very large, I needed to increase the clips to view the models without limitations of view, but soon after I diminish them and that's where it began to cause problems.

[image]
[image]