# Graphics problem when viewing in user perspective

Tags: scene

When I view my scene in "User Perspective" mode, my graphics are glitched out (both solid and texture modes).

When I switch to ortho everything looks fine, so does the final render.

On the left is a plain old vanilla sphere (no modifications) - on the right is a cylinder with holes cut out.

[image]

I'm using 2x GTX-770 graphics cards (CUDA) in preferences.

Any Ideas?

Cheers.

Comment: What settings are set for clipping in the viewport on the Properties shelf > View rollout? See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/shadows-along-edges-of-mesh-in-3d-view/1387#1387

Comment: @MrZak Nice one! My start clip was set to "0". I changed it to 1mm and the problem went away. Thanks man.