# Weird triangle pattern on edge of model

Tags: modeling

Hi everyone I am trying to model a gun in blender and I am getting these wierd edge as you can see on the right hand side of the second image. There are some triangles or I don't know what that is. Does anyone know how to fix it?

[image][image]

Comment: Perhaps check the 'wire' option in Object Properties  > Display so we can see your topology.

Comment: I have added two more images check them out.Thanks for help

Comment: Check your rendered model. Some times it do appears due to aliasing and doesn't appear when u render due to anti-aliasing .

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/shadows-along-edges-of-mesh-in-3d-view Try to change clipping values in viewport

Comment: Even after importing that mesh in 3ds max as a fbx .Those wired triangles are still visible

Answer (score -2):

From those images, I can only guess. Is it only visible in edit mode? Is it only on that edge? Have you tried to rule out usual suspects? Remove doubles, recalc normals?

Try this: add a bevel modifier to your object with segments > 2, does it disappear? if so you should be fine and this is only a viewport issue.

Comment: If you need to clarify details these should be done as comments on the question, not as an answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, but 
1. I wasn't allowed to comment at that time
2. That is an answer: first try the usual suspects, if that doesn't help use the Bevel etc.