# Gemoetry glitches in viewport

Tags: 3d-view

My Blender started acting wierd after I bought a brand new graphics card, because the old one fried. The geometry in viewport is all glitched, but what is more wierd when I look at it through camera or render it, everything is fine.
Here are examples, in the first picture I have enabled backface culling and in the second one I deleted everything, and created brand new cube also I have disabled backface culling. For some reason backface culling reduces the flickering but it is still present.

[image]

[image]

The graphics card is Radeon RX 580 with 8GB of memory if it helps in any way.

I have tried reinstalling blender, I made sure that my graphic card's drivers are up to date. I tried every method from Window Draw Method in user settings.The card's fine, I don't see any glitches anywhere else just in blender viewport. I would appriciate any suggestions cause I looked through various forums and couldn't find anyone with similiar problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try decreasing end clip value and increasing low clip value on the Properties shelf (N), see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/shadows-along-edges-of-mesh-in-3d-view

Comment: Oh jeez...it was that simple. Never would have thought of that. I've set the Start value of Clip to '0'. It seems that blender didn't know what to do with that, hence the glitches...I've set it to 1 cm and everything is fine now. Thank you very much. Cheers