# How to change edit mode display?

Tags: interface, edit-mode

I somehow changed the way my meshes are displayed in edit mode :

[image: Bad Edit mode display]

Do you know how to return to the original display that is provided by default in Blender ? I've tryed many options in Properties panel and in User Preferences.

It happens only in "User Ortho" view.

Comment: Pressing Numkey 5 will get you out of Ortho view

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1385/30849) problem.

Comment: Yes @Leander this is same problem. Do you know if as I had switched to the metric system, it could have had a negative impact on the clip end value ?
Many thanks for your response-comment, I set the clip end to 10 meter, so now I see my scene a bit cut, but the main problem is gone :)

Comment: You can also set the Near plane to a little higher value. Then maybe you can set the far plane to a  value which allows you to view your whole scene. The problem arises when the span between the near and far plane is too large.