# Just opened my project and it looks like this

Tags: mesh

Yesterday when I saved it was ok but now it looks horrible. Also when rendering it looks normal so its a viewport bug but its hard to work with something like this
[image]

Comment: Hello :). This is not necessarily a bug: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1385/, https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/4946/