# Wierd Jagged edges in Viewport Shading mode, how to fix?

Tags: 3d-view

When in viewport shading mode, (and any other eevee modes...) I get these annoying, weird jagged edges I've never encountered before. Any idea how to fix it? I'm sure it's a hotkey I pressed without knowing, but it is hard to look at.

[image: Image of the jagged edges]

Comment: Hello :). This looks like *z-fighting* caused by too large clipping distance https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1387/

Comment: @JachymMichal You are totally right! I my clipping distance was much too small. Set it to 0.01 and it fixed it, thank you Jachym!

Comment: Happy to help :). Good luck with your project.