# Faces visible through other objects when viewed at a range

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to render a building, and the top of the building is partially showing through the platform on the roof when I pull back the view. The platform is already .1m above the roof. I can make it no longer show through if I raise the platform more, but then the platform is in the wrong place.

[image]

When I zoom in, there isn't a problem. Is there a setting I'm missing or something?

The building is 300m tall. The clipping goes away when I space it 1m from the roof. This example shows clipping at .1m. The camera is about 500m from the building.

The surfaces aren't overlapping, so I wouldn't think that z-fighting would take place, even though that's what it looks like.

Comment: What is the Scale and Dimension of the building an roof?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cause of black artifacts in render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render)

Comment: Check the clipping-range of your camera is appropriate to the  min and max camera -> feature distances during the shot. (In extreme cases, you can  key-frame those)

Comment: @Leander, these faces are not overlapping, so z-fighting shouldn't apply, unless I'm hitting a resolution limit I'm not aware of.

Comment: Yes, probably the latter. Listening the Robin Betts' advice will redistribute the buckets considered same depth, so if you decrease the clipping range, the visible range will be smaller and so each bucket will be smaller and it will be less likely for two faces to end up in the same bucket.

Comment: It is still z-fighting caused by the limited precision of floating point numbers. Did Robin Betts' suggestion solve your problem.

Comment: So, funny thing, I was looking at the object in the viewport, not through the camera. When I switched to the camera, the artifacts went away. Was not expecting that.

Comment: Viewport can have different clipping range than camera.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady, so it would seem. My apologies for bugging you all with a noob issue. Would one of you like to post that as an answer, or should I take a whack at it? I can alter the question with details as necessary.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/shadows-along-edges-of-mesh-in-3d-view https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport

Comment: Thanks, @DuarteFarrajotaRamos. The issue seems to be that there are numerous pieces of information that need to be combined to solve this problem. "Z-fighting will produce these artifacts," "Clipping needs to be set separately for viewport and render," and also "Broader clipping range can induce z-fighting" None of the listed questions actually combines these, so I'll write my own answer.