# Topology Clipping in Camera View

Tags: modeling, mesh, camera

Sorry if this looks like a duplicate but my question was not solved. I am reposting this question because it was wrongfully closed. they linked this post: [Shadows along edges of mesh in 3D View](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/shadows-along-edges-of-mesh-in-3d-view) and it did not solve my problem in the slightest. The camera clip start and end settings do not solve my problem.

The only thing even close to a solution is this line: "I encountered this issue again and my fix mentioned above helped nothing. I did, however, solve it by opening the properties panel (N), making my way down to the Mesh Display twirldown and unchecking the box for Faces underneath the Overlays area.

-- The Mesh Display twirldown appears in Edit mode, but not in Object Mode."

However i cant find the mesh display menu they mention anywhere. There is a properties panel in the N menu but it opens to nothing

[image]

I am having a problem with the viewport wireframe mode. I am trying to render a turntable of a model with the wireframe on but when i look at it through the camera both sides of the mesh are visible. The first picture is through the camera and the second is normal viewport. I would like the rendered camera view to look like the second picture. There isnt much point of a wireframe view if you see through the model when looking at it through the camera. Again sorry if this appears like a duplicate question but the post i was linked did not solve my issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe a camera clipping problem? (Camera panel > Lens> Clip Start and End)

Comment: Hello ty for the response! The clip start and end doesnt solve the problem unfortunately.